# Finding an inverse relationship with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to find all Captains that **do not** have a boat with the classification sailboat. I can find all captains with a sailboat, but can't figure out how to do the inverse using ActiveRecord.

```
class Captain < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :boats
end

class Boat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :captain
  has_many    :boat_classifications
  has_many    :classifications, through: :boat_classifications
end

class BoatClassification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :boat
  belongs_to :classification
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind a little sql, you can left join the captain to their boats and classifications and select the ones that don't have a sailboat.

```
Captain.joins("
  LEFT JOIN boats ON captains.id = boats.captain_id
  LEFT JOIN boat_classifications ON boats.id = boat_classifications.boat_id
  LEFT JOIN classifications ON boat_classifications.classification_id = classifications.id AND classifications.name = 'Sailboat'
").where("classifications.id IS NULL")
```

Or use your existing ones and use sql to select the captains not in that group

```
Captain.where("id NOT IN (?)", Captain.sailors.map(&:id))
```

Comment: Perfect! I replaced `map` with `pluck` so `Captain.where("id NOT IN (?)", Captain.sailors.pluck(:id))`